# Service Worker - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, service-worker

I have made a web app and have used service worker in my app. It's all working fine when online. The files are all cached when we run the app for the first time. But I get this error when it goes offline.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I don't know why this error is occurring!

I have used pwabuilder.com for adding service worker and manifest to the web app.

This is the pwabuilder-sw.js file:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
event.waitUntil(preLoad());
});

var preLoad = function() {
console.log('[PWA Builder] Install Event processing');
return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
    console.log('[PWA Builder] Cached index and offline page during 
Install');
    return cache.addAll([
        '/manup.js',
        'pwabuilder-sw-register.js',
        'pwabuilder-sw.js',
        'manifest.json',
        '/js/angular.min.js',
        '/js/script.js',
        '/js/materialize.min.js',
        '/css/materialize.min.css',
        '/css/style.css',
        '/offline.html',
        '/index.html'
    ]);
});
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
console.log('The service worker is serving the asset.');
event.respondWith(checkResponse(event.request).catch(function() {
    return returnFromCache(event.request)
}));
event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
});

var checkResponse = function(request) {
return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 404) {
            fulfill(response)
        } else {
            reject()
        }
    }, reject)
});
};

var addToCache = function(request) {
return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
    return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        console.log('[PWA Builder] add page to offline' + response.url)
        return cache.put(request, response);
    });
});
};

var returnFromCache = function(request) {
return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function(matching) {
        if (!matching || matching.status == 404) {
            return cache.match('offline.html')
        } else {
            return matching
        }
    });
});
};
```

This is the pwabuilder-sw-register.js file:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
  console.log('[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register')
} else {
  //Register the ServiceWorker
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('pwabuilder-sw.js', {
    scope: './'
  }).then(function (reg) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered for scope:' +
      reg.scope);
  });
}
```

Any clues?!

Comment: for which of the cached url do you get this error? for all?

Answer (score 3):

I found a scenario that this error occurs.

Certain ad block extension blocks the google analytics js file, it would cause the service worker break when fetching.

Disabling the ad block extension could prevent this.

Comment: I agree completely. I saw this question yesterday and today looking to the console i found the adblock was blocking some requests to google ads and youtube ads, so i came back to answer it and you already did it :-)

Comment: Excluding the ga URL from the control of service worker fetch could also resolve this. This is more gentle, compared to disabling AdBlock extension directly. https://github.com/Leslie-Wong-H/game_of_life/blob/master/src/service-worker.js#L16

Comment: the fetch event still working for the next urls even the fetch fails returning an error and the ga still blocked even the url is returned by the fetch event. The Service Worker only will fail if you try to add it to the cache.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error has I was trying to cache an entire directory instead of a single file.
My guess is that you have a URL that fails to cache and so the entire caching operation fails as well as the cache is atomic meaning: If a single URL fails the entire cache fail.

Comment: Exactly. The error that op is seeing on the logs does not break the Service Worker, it is just a log. But if the url is blocked and you try to cache it, all the cache will be aborted, just in that event.